# Typical dissipation constant of average thermistor?

Tags: thermistor, dissipation

What is the typical dissipation constant of average thermistor? I.e. how much current I can feed to thermistor without significant self-heating?

I know that I can measure exact value for particular thermistor, but I wondered whether there was some kind of typical values like 3 mW/°C, "1ma should be ok" or so.

Comment: Quite hard to answer. For example, I'm using NTCs from Joyin (JNR07RxxxM65) and their DPs vary between 8 and 12mW/K, and maximum allowable steady state currents do between 1.2 and 3.0 Amperes. Likewise, some SMD thermistors have DP between 3 and 9 mW/K.

Comment: **Impossible to answer** there is no "average thermistor". You should narrow down the exact application of the thermistor and then you could ask what a typical type of thermistor would in that case be a good choice.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Those sound like inrush current limiters.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the datasheet you should find a number. If no datasheet you can 'guess' by comparing a similar size and package part (confirm the lead material is the same to be closer to the truth).

You should also look deeper and find the **conditions** under which the dissipation factor is measured (typically in an application note or manual, rather than in each individual datasheet). Ideally something like 'still air, 1°C above ambient, and 50mm leads'. Not so ideally, something like silicone oil flowing at 1m/s (well that would be a bit extreme, but you get the idea). The exact same part immersed in oil or with forced convection will have a very different factor from that in still air.

Here is is a typical thermistor [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/29048/ntcle203.pdf) specification:

[image]

Note, for example, the conditions under which they measure the 'response time'.

If you use a series resistor to a fixed voltage source you would normally  pick that resistance to be close to the normal operating temperature (to maximize the resolution, which will fall off dramatically at higher and lower temperatures for common NTC thermistor types which change around 5%/°C). Of course that also maximizes the self-heating at that point since the thermistor resistance matches the Thevenin-equivalent source resistance. For example, a 10K thermistor in series with 10K 1% will have a power dissipation maxima at the temperature where it is 10K, and it will be ~0.6mW with a 5V supply.

Answer (score 1):

the "average" new designer ;) might 1st learn about about thermistor self-heating and want to keep it low such as possible or just less than the accuracy you want to achieve.

e.g. +/- 1'C with 0.5 self heating max.

The resolution, accuracy and self-heating current are design tradeoffs.

**Size matters**.

### Not only for self heating limits but improved latency to ambient being measured

- As you can see in the datasheet of "THE" most common thermistor value, 10k, in an SMD part, they come in 3 sizes each rated for 1, 2 or 3 mW/'C

[image]
Since more regulated voltage on the bridge gives more resolution it also gives more self-heat. However resolution of detection can also be improved using more digital resolution or more clever means using DAC's and ADC's

Thus only you can decide how to measure this and meet your required resolution and accuracy.

One must also consider the ambient air flow and latency between heat or cold source and sensor, which can greatly affect the regulator stability and result in overshoot of temperatures using ON/OFF controllers.  Better heating systems use proportional control of heat such as valve controlled steam or water flow.
Hysteresis controls

Old household designs using thermal sensor coils & mercury switches. They also had a "set-back" self-heater coil to heat the thermal coil sensor and thus reduce the amount of hysteresis and resulting overshoot of furnace in a mechanical thermal switch. One could use this method (with external small heat resistor or use software) to reduce hysteresis and overshoot at the expense of more frequent corrections of ON/OFF control.  But , this is essentially adding prediction or derivative feedback to what we call PID feedback control, which is the best method for regulating temperature. (Proportional, integral, derivative feedback and/or loop control).

Cheap digital thermostats often do not perform as well as these ancient analog counterparts because they neglected hysteresis effects on overshoot.

Generally the smaller sensor gives the fastest convection thermal response for air contact but also reduces the power level from self-heating. ... another trade-off, but worthy of consideration.

> Another way to increase resolution but reduce self-heating is to pulse the thermistor bridge during a brief sample and hold. With a low duty cycle, one can raise the resolution and accuracy x10 by using <10% duty cycle.